# Where can I learned about important warrior macros?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

As mentioned in the previous posts I have recently rolled a dps arms warrior.  I am interested in both dungeons and pvp.  What site is a good starting point for learning important warrior macros?

Comment: This is sadly a question asking for a list, which does not work will with the question/answer format of this site. You're probably better off asking on some kind of forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WoWWiki](http://www.wowwiki.com/Useful_macros) and [Wowpedia](http://www.wowpedia.org/Useful_macros) keep documented lists of "useful macros". Beyond that, WoW Macros has sections for macros based on classes (such as their [warrior](http://wowmacros.com/warrior-macros.html) section) and World of Warcraft Macros Database does [the same thing](http://www.wowmacroswarcraft.com/category/warrior-macros/). Some of these macros can be a bit dated, but generally-speaking you can find some useful stuff.